# rails search form with pg_search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, pg-search

Here I would like to have one search form for different models User & Post

The result should be seen in different partial views.

The search controller is like

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.search(params[:query])
    @posts = Post.search(params[:query])
  end
end
```

So that I can use partial to see results of both users and posts

I am using pg_search, so the model is like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search, :against => [:name]
end


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search, :against => [:content]
end
```

My question is how I get the :query form search form? and to pass the :query to search controller?

```
  <%= form_tag(XXXXX_path, method: "get") do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, nil, placeholder: "Search ...", class: "form-control" %>
    <%= submit_tag "", style: "display: none;" %>
  <% end %>
```

What is XXXXX should be on above code to make the controller get :query? since I don't want to have another search model

Or is there any other way to have the search form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want `XXXXX` to be called. I would recommend calling it something like `search_path`. You would have to make some changes though to pass `:query` to your controller.

In your [`routes.rb`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code) file you could have something like (check out the link for additional routing needs based on your code):

```
get '/search' => 'search#index'
```

In your view you are naming the param as `:search`, that is okay but in your controller you would have to reference `params[:search]` in order for it to be available.

If you want the param to be called `:query` you would have to change the `text_field_tag` to match.